# Correlation coefficient of metrices (or, 2d arrays)

Tags: c#, image-processing, correlation, cross-correlation, pearson-correlation

I need to compute the correlation coefficient between two digital images so that I can compare those two images [to test their similarities](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50282799_Multidirectional_Scratch_Detection_and_Restoration_in_Digitized_Old_Images).

I can convert the images either to two [matrices of complex numbers](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Imaging/ComplexImage.cs) (the complex representation of the images are Fourier Transformed so that I can work in frequency domain) or to two [matrices of real numbers](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Imaging/Converters/ImageToMatrix.cs). So, those are my options to get started with.

**How can I calculate the correlation coefficient of two matrices (or 2d arrays)?**

[This routine](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Math/Metrics/PearsonCorrelation.cs) can calculate correlation coefficient of two vectors (or 1d arrays). But, I need to calculate the correlation of two matrices (or, 2d arrays).

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way for a 2d array. You could just copy your 2d arrays (M rows, N columns) into 1d array of size MxN and use the algorithm you already have.

The order doesn't matter at all, you could do rows first or something else. The only thing that is important is to use the same order for both arrays so that corresponding pixels are compared.

Comment: Can u give me any idea, Why doesn't that AForge framework have any such routine for 2d arrays, given that images are 2d and that framework is intended mostly for image processing/computer vision?

Comment: @anonymous: I don't know this framework. But maybe it has a function to calculate a 2d autocorrelation function. If you pass 0 to both arguments of that function, it will return the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Can you provide me with any reference in support of your answer (not the comment)?

Comment: For example Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient What's important, the correlation coefficient has nothing to do with how the data are stored, in a 1d, 2d, or 1000d array. Only the values are important.